# Ansible playbook returns "pickle data was truncated, insecure string pickle"

Tags: python, ansible

```
- hosts: Router

  tasks:

  - name: show int fa4 ip address
    ios_command:
      commands: show run int fa4
    become: yes
    become_method: enable


    register: Teste
  - debug: var=Teste.stdout_lines
```

I get the below error:

```
fatal: [Router]: FAILED! => {"msg": "pickle data was truncated"}
```

Using Ansible version: 2.6.1

Added the following to playbook:
`gather_facts: no`

The error changed to:

```
fatal: [Router]: FAILED! => {"msg": "insecure string pickle"}
```

Has anyone seen this/have a solution?

Comment: Such errors have been seen in Python, in example [pickle data was truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637809/) or [insecure string pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746825/).