# Pickle data was truncated (desktop streaming)

Tags: python, sockets, streaming, pickle

I'm trying to build a desktop streaming app. It consists of a server and a client for now. I learned that I should use the library pickle in order to serialize/deserialize the data. However, when I run both the scripts, I get the error "Pickle data was truncated" from the client side. Could you help me to solve this? I tried the solution the following link, whose OP apparently was trying to do the similar think but it didn't work.

[python 3.6 socket pickle data was truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637809/python-3-6-socket-pickle-data-was-truncated)

Server

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab
import socket
import pickle

HOST = "0.0.0.0"
SOCKET = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST,SOCKET))


while True:
    s.listen(5)
    client, addres = s.accept()
    print(addres, " has connected")
    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    img_np = np.array(img)
    img_np_serial = pickle.dumps(img_np)
    client.send(img_np_serial)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Client

```
import socket
import pickle

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()),5000))

data = b""
while True:
    packet = s.recv(4096)
    if not packet: break
    data += packet

    data_deserial = pickle.loads(data)
    print((data_deserial))
```

Comment: you should use `pickle.loads` after `while True`, not inside loop.

Comment: This time I didn't get an error. But the print statement just returns empty. Is it normal? @furas

Comment: check `len(img)`, `len(img_np_serial)` in server, and `len(data)` `len(data_deserial)` in client.