# How to stream a webcam with Python using socket, pickle, and OpenCV?

Tags: python, sockets, opencv, video-streaming, pickle

In Python I need to stream the webcam of a user but I have a problem while receiving the data. I use pickle to send a list called data that contains the sender's identity, the data type (a msg, a command, and image) and the data itself. Problem is that when I send an image with pickle, an error occurs.

Server code :

```py
import socket
import threading
import pickle

class Server:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    connections = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
        self.sock.listen(5)
        print("Server created")
    def handler(self, c, a):
        while True:
            try:
                raw_data = c.recv(1024)
            except ConnectionResetError:
                print("Error")
                print(str(a[0]) + ':' + str(a[1]), "disconnected roughly")
                self.connections.remove(c)
                c.close()
                break
            except:
                print("Error while recieving data")
                continue

            for connection in self.connections:
                if connection != c:
                    connection.sendall(raw_data)
            if not raw_data:
                print(str(a[0]) + ':' + str(a[1]), "disconnected")
                self.connections.remove(c)
                c.close()
                break

    def run(self):
        print("Server is running")
        while True:
            try:
                c, a = self.sock.accept()
                print(str(a[0]) + ':' + str(a[1]), "connected")
            except:
                print("Error during client connection")
                continue
            cThread = threading.Thread(target=self.handler, args=(c, a), name="HandlerTh")
            cThread.daemon = True
            cThread.start()
            self.connections.append(c)


def main():
    server = Server()
    server.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
```

The client which sends the webcam stream :

```py
## Import modules
import socket
import threading
import pickle

import cv2, numpy as np

## CLIENT CLASS INITIALISATION ##
class Client:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    count = 0
    keys = []

    def __init__(self,server_ip = '127.0.0.1' ,server_port = 1234):
        self.sock.connect((server_ip, server_port))

        promptThread = threading.Thread(target=self.prompt, name="bPrompt")
        promptThread.daemon = True
        promptThread.start()
        self.KL_STATE = 0
        self.EYE_STATE = 0
        while True:
            raw_data = self.sock.recv(4096)
            data = pickle.loads(raw_data)
            # data[0] = ID
            # data[1] = DATA_TYPE
            # data[2] = CMD_DATA
            if data[1] == "command":
                self.execute_command(data[2])
            elif not data:
                break
            print(data)


## DATA TREATMENT ##

    def send_data(self,data_type,data):
        raw_data = ["vb",data_type,data]
        data_p = pickle.dumps(raw_data)
        self.sock.sendall(data_p)

    def execute_command(self,command):
        if command == "Eye-start":
            eyeThread = threading.Thread(target=self.eye, name="EyeTh")
            self.EYE_STATE = 1
            eyeThread.start()
        elif command == "Eye-stop":
            self.stopTool("Eye")

        else:
            print("unknown command")
            self.send_data("log_msg","unknown command")


    def prompt(self):
        while True:
            command = input("client@v >")
            self.send_data("command",command)
## KIT ##

    def stopTool(self,tool):
        if tool == "Eye-stop":
            self.EYE_STATE = 0
        else:
            msg = f"{tool} dont exist"
            print(msg)
            self.send_data("stopTool-log",msg)

## 2nd tool : eye
    def eye(self):
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while self.EYE_STATE == 1:
            check, frame = video.read()
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            self.send_data("eye",gray)
            if self.EYE_STATE == 0:
                break
        cv2.destroyAllWindows
        video.release()


## MAIN PROGRAM ##

def main ():
    client = Client()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
```

And then the client which sends the command :

```py
import socket
import threading
import pickle
import datetime

import cv2, numpy as np

TIME = datetime.datetime.now()
TIME = TIME.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

class Client:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def __init__(self):
        self.sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1234))

        iThread = threading.Thread(target=self.prompt, name="aPromptTh")
        iThread.daemon = True
        iThread.start()

        while True:
            raw_data = self.sock.recv(4096)
            data = pickle.loads(raw_data)
            # print(data)

            if data[1] == "eye":
                cv2.imshow("Window name",data[2])

            else:
                print(data)
            if not data:
                break


    def prompt(self):
        while True:
            command = input("client@a >")
            raw_data = ["a","command",command]
            self.send_data(raw_data)

    def send_data(self,data):
        # while True:
        data = pickle.dumps(data)
        self.sock.sendall(data)

client = Client()
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\**\**.py", line **, in <module>
    client = Client()
  File "C:\Users\**\**.py", line **, in __init__
    data = pickle.loads(raw_data)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44637809/11301900)?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what is happening here is that, when you are sending the image file, it has to get broken up into packets and your image is too large to fit into 1 packet. So, the image is sent in multiple packets.

Your program attempts to receive only the first packet, which does not contain the full pickled image, and then unpickle it, which throws an error.

Instead, try something like:

```
while True:
    raw_data = b""
    while True:
        packet = s.recv(4096)
        if not packet: 
            break
        raw_data += packet
    data = pickle.loads(raw_data)
    if data[1] == "eye":
        cv2.imshow("Window name",data[2])

    else:
        print(data)
    if not data:
        break
```