# Only sometimes, I get _pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated

Tags: python, sockets, pickle, bytesio

i'm getting some occasional Unpickling errors, but more times than not, it works fine. Essentially I'm generating images on the server side, and using pickle to transmit them to the client side.

Essentially, I am using my send() function to let the client know how many bytes the pickled data is, so it can use rscSock.recv() with the amount of bytes+1 when I use conn.send(graphs) to prevent this exact thing. And it works, most of the time. Occasionally I'm getting pickle truncated, and I can't seem to find out why. I tried using a while loop to receive it in blocks of 4096 from code I found on here ([python 3.6 socket pickle data was truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637809/python-3-6-socket-pickle-data-was-truncated)), but it hangs on the recv. Not sure what to do.

Server Code:

```
elif cmd['cmd'] == 'RSC_VIEW_GRAPHS':
                            graphs = pickle.dumps(genGraphs(userSession['uid'], cmd['arg0'], cmd['arg1']))
                            send(conn, 'RSC_IMG_DATA', len(graphs))
                            conn.send(graphs)
                            del graphs
```

Client Code

```
send(rscSock, 'RSC_VIEW_GRAPHS', radioVar.get(), str(dateObj.date()))
            resp = receive(rscSock)
            if resp['resp'] == 'RSC_IMG_DATA':
                graphs = pickle.loads(rscSock.recv(int(resp['arg0'])+1))
```

The graphs variable being fulfilled by the genGraphs() function is returning an array of BytesIO objects, as shown here by the end of the genGraphs() function:

```
        imgs = []
        for x in statDict:
            # Filler Code removed, irrelevant to post
            imgs.append(io.BytesIO())
            plt.savefig(imgs[-1], format='png')
            plt.close()
        return imgs
```

And lastly, here are the send() and receive() functions for both the client and server:

Client

```
def send(conn, cmd, *argv): 
    try:
        cmdObj = {'cmd': cmd}
        
        y = 0
        for x in argv:
            cmdObj['arg'+str(y)] = x
            y+=1
        
        cmdObj['key'] = sessionKey
        
        obj = str.encode(json.dumps(cmdObj))
        objLen = str(len(obj)).encode()
        
        if conn.send(objLen):
            if conn.recv(12).decode() == "RSC_LEN_OK":
                if conn.send(obj):
                    if debug == 1: print("Sending '", obj, "' with length '", objLen ,"'")
                    return True
        return False
    except (ConnectionResetError, ConnectionAbortedError):
        if cmdObj['arg1'] == 0:
            return True
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Real Estate Stat Counter", "Lost server connection. Please log back in.")
            return False

def receive(conn):
    try:
        dataSize = int(conn.recv(8))
        if dataSize < 16384:
            conn.send(str.encode("RSC_LEN_OK"))
            data = json.loads(conn.recv(dataSize).decode())
            if debug == 1: print("Received '", data, "' with length '", dataSize ,"'")
            return data
        else:
            conn.send(str.encode("RSC_LEN_NO"))
            return False
    except (OSError, UnicodeDecodeError, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError) as e:
        return False
```

Server

```
def send(conn, resp, *argv):
    try:
        respObj = {'resp': resp}
        
        y = 0
        for x in argv:
            respObj["arg"+str(y)] = x
            y+=1
        
        obj = str.encode(json.dumps(respObj))
        objLen = str(len(obj)).encode()
        
        if conn.send(objLen):
            if conn.recv(12).decode() == "RSC_LEN_OK":
                if conn.send(obj):
                    if debug == 1: print("Sending '", obj, "' with length '", objLen ,"'")
                    return True
        logging.log("WARN: send() failure")
        return False
    except ConnectionResetError:
        logging.log("INFO: Client connection lost, terming socket")
        conn.close()
    return False

def receive(conn):
    try:
        dataSize = int(conn.recv(8))
        if dataSize < 16384:
            conn.send(str.encode("RSC_LEN_OK"))
            data = json.loads(conn.recv(dataSize).decode())
            if debug == 1: print("Received '", data, "' with length '", dataSize ,"'")
            return data
        else:
            conn.send(str.encode("RSC_LEN_NO"))
            return False
    except (OSError, UnicodeDecodeError, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError) as e:
        logging.log("WARN: receive() received raw data:", conn.recv(16384).decode())
        logging.log("WARN: receive() exception:", e)
        return False
    except ValueError:
        logging.log("WARN: receive() did not get a valid byte length first")
        return False
```

Comment: `.recv(dataSize)` doesn't guarantee that it will receive the entire specified amount, it will return immediately with whatever data has been received, *up to* the specified amount.  It's your responsibility to loop (or otherwise arrange for further calls to `.recv()`) until the full amount has been accumulated.

Comment: That makes sense, could i perhaps catch the exception with

Answer (score 0):

So based on jasonharper's comment, I ended up revising only the client code:

```
                data = []
                while len(b"".join(data)) < int(resp['arg0']):
                    data.append(rscSock.recv(4096))
                graphs = pickle.loads(b"".join(data))
```

Now it will check in a loop if it's received the amount of bytes that it was originally told before sending the BytesIO object array.

Working good so far!!